# I can't find simulator on swift

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

[image]

I can't find simulator on swift I install simulator version 15

[image]

but my simulator list only have any iOS device(arm 64)and my Mac
I don't know how to add simulator to my list please help me

Answer (score 0):

From the top left

`Xcode > Preferences > Components`

and install the most recent simulator from the list.

Then go to  `Window > Devices and Simuators > Simulators` and tap on `+` icon on the bottom left and create a new simulator.

Comment: very thanks about your comment. I think about this problem 2days thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you open the framework/app which has already setup their deployment target. Which current device of yours doesn't have this.

Open xcode project and go to tab Info -> Deployment target -> iOS Deployment Target -> change iOS version

[image]

Comment: thank you so much I think about this problem about 2days thanks a lot